# integration of this trigonometric expression

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the integration of the following expression $$\int \frac{\cos(4x)+1}{\cot(x)-\tan(x)}$$ .So after doing some trigonometry work I got it converted into $tan(x)$ and it becomes $$\int \frac{tan(x)-tan^3(x)}{(1+tan^2(x))^2}$$ but I dont know how to proceed from here. Putting $tan(x)=t$ also doesnt help. Hope you guys help me thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$\cos4x=2\cos^22x-1$$

$$\cot x-\tan x=\cdots=\dfrac{2\cos2x}{\sin2x}$$

$$\dfrac{\cos4x+1}{\cot x-\tan x}=?$$

Use $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$